# Office add-in - support for form fields

Tags: office365, office-js

I am migrating an add-in built for earlier versions of office to Office 2016/Office 365 and am planning to implement the functionality now as Office Add-in using office.js etc .

The add-in parses the document and extracts meta-data ( from form-fields, book-marked fields or mail-merge  fields ) and submits the document to a server. While I could find some support for form-fields in Office 2016 for windows, the same was not working for office 365. And in my search I did not find support for book-marked fields and mail-merged fields in office javascript library.

Can anyone let me know the extent to which this functionality is available in various versions of office and the support for the same in the office-js libraries

Regards
Hari

Answer (score 2):

Hello access to fields is not currently supported in the JavaScript API. Its on our backlog, not ETAs available at this point.

Comment: Any timeline on the next release of the Javascript API?